# Dynamically create buttons with different event calls

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic, cordova

I have a problem in the following JavaScript function.

I am trying to create buttons dynamically based on details from the `results` variable.

The button are created and an event is attached but it seems each button has the exact same event attached.

I need the address variable to be different for each event attached to a button and for that button then to be added to replace text in my `macField` variable.

```
function (results) {
    var r;
    var x, i;
    var btn;
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        app.display("Paired to" + results[i].name + results[i].address);
        x = document.getElementById("message2");
        r = results[i].address;
        w = document.getElementById('macField').value;
        btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('macField').value = r;
        };
        btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btn.setAttribute('name', 'sal' + [i]);
        btn.setAttribute('id', 'Button' + [i]);
        btn.setAttribute('value', results[i].name);
        appendChild(btn);
    }
}

function (error) {
    app.display(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use immediate function. Change this part:

```
 btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('macField').value = r;
 };
```

like this:

```
 (function(r){
   btn.onclick = function () {
       document.getElementById('macField').value = r;
     };
 })(r);
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/uebD8/1/

Comment: Wow that was fast ,Just tried it there and it worked never seen a function done like that before ,sorry to ask but is there any explanation you can give on it and how it works?

Comment: you welcome , you can read it here for example: http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/javascript-immediate-functions-basics/

Comment: This is a genius solution I've never thought to do before! Usually what I do is assign a custom attribute to the button that stores the value I want to use, then make the onclick function use that attribute. But this is a far more efficient method.

As for how it works Maria88:
In your code, all your onclick events all access the same "r" variable, as there is only (and this is completely wrong terminology, but I lack a better way to describe) one "copy" of the r variable. Using a closure likes this creates "multiple copies" of the r variable. (Very, very bad terminolgy but I am tired)

Comment: Look i have limited rep here so cant add your plus 1 but ,a thanks is definitly in order was looking at that for ages ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

create your function seperately like below

```
    function macFieldValue(val)    
{
    document.getElementById('macField').value = val;
}
```

and set button onclick attribute like this

```
btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'macFieldValue('+r+')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modifying this part:

```
btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('macField').value = r;
};
```

to

```
btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.setAttribute('some_id', r);
btn.addEventListener('click',
function (e) {
    var addr = e.source.some_id;
    document.getElementById('macField').value = addr;
}, false);
```

You are hitting an unfortunate curse of JS. Your code would have worked if it wasn't within a for-loop. In any case, you should be using addEventListener.